# PHPStorm 8.0.3 and Remote ssh phpunit bug

Tags: php, phpunit, phpstorm

I was following [this](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Running+PHPUnit+tests+over+SSH+on+a+remote+server+with+PhpStorm#RunningPHPUnittestsoverSSHonaremoteserverwithPhpStorm-1.ConfiguringPHPUnitByRemoteInterpreter) official tutorial on how to run phpunit tests via ssh to another server. Everything went fine, until I actually created test configuration and tried to run the test. The error that I'm getting is this:

```
ssh://root@172.17.0.1:22/usr/bin/php /root/.phpstorm_helpers/phpunit.php --no-configuration /opt/container/www/app/lib/tests
Testing started at 19.51 ...
bash: line 0: cd: /opt/container/www/app/lib: No such file or directory
Cannot open file "/opt/container/www/app/lib/tests.php".
```

So I figured that actually the problem is in the path to the test folder. But this is the thing, in this dialog:

[image: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/download/attachments/53345260/test-configuration.png?version=1&modificationDate=1401444064000]

directory of the test folder must be located using the local file system, but the actual test folder is on the remote machine and has a different path. As a test, I created '/opt/container/www/app/lib/tests' path on remote server, and voila, phpunit is running successfully. So, the point is that I can't put in the Directory input box the real location of the test folder on remote server, and the tutorial doesn't say nothing about that. Did I miss somethimg, or this is really a bug ?

EDIT:
Here is my current configuration:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/5BnTrZZ.png]

where directory points to the directory on local file system

Remote interpreter configured:

[image]

And

[image]

I was able actually to select autload.php from remote server.

Comment: How did you configure your SSH/PHP Interpreter? Screenshots please.

Comment: I have updated the question with the screens, thanks.

Comment: Please create a Deployment entry of SFTP type and configure it for this project (mark as default as well). Then please create another PHP Interpreter using that SFTP entry (and not SSH details directly). Use that newly created Interpreter for this project. Should help. Obviously, all test folders/files should be located under the project for IDE to be able to map local path to remote ones.

Comment: Wow, this works, thanks! I still have some include path issues, but hopefully I'll be able to sort them out.

Comment: The error that I'm getting is now 'PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: Class "PHPUnit_Extensions_RepeatedTest" does not extend PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase.' ,  tried a few things and can't really fix it...also seems that phpstorm is running phpunit from '/root/.phpstorm_helpers/phpunit.php', is there a way I can set phpunit location that composer installed ?

Comment: Nevermind, I was able to fix. Once again, thanks!

Comment: @Zed What was they solution? Can you add an answer? I've got the *exactly* the same issue.

Comment: @LazyOne So your solution worked for me as well. There was only one difference - the directory in the Debug configuration is referred with one level up i.e. if I have `a/b/c` then it refers to `a/b`. Hence the mapping in the deployment should also have `a/b`.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone having in PHPStorm error like:

```
PHP Fatal error: Uncaught PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: Class ... not found...
```

You have to install phpunit by composer on project level:

- by add phpunit to project composer.json file in require-dev section and run **composer update**,
- by run **composer require phpunit/phpunit** in project root directory,